# Problemas com função sum() dentro de summarise usando plyr e tidyverse!

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Olá, boa tarde!

Estou encontrando dificuldades em utilizar `tidyverse`, para realizar uma função de empilhar + `summarise(soma=sum(value))` + desempilhar = `base%>%pivot_longer(cols=(),names_to(),values_to())%>%group_by()%>%summarise(soma=sum(value))%>%spread(variable,m)`. Ao utilizar este código modificando apenas a função dentro de `summarise()`, de `sum()` para `mean()` ou `sd()`, sempre funcionou, agora para `sum()`, não funciona, ele não soma, apenas repete o valor.

Pra verificar, utilizei `reshape2::dcast(plyr::ddply(reshape2::melt()))` que era a função que sempre tive o hábito de utilizar, além de confrontar com a função `sum()` aplicado aos valores em um `subset()` determinado.

gostaria do auxílo de vocês para verificar como utilizar por `tidyverse`, de preferencia sem aquelas saidas de **"`summarise()` ... (override with `.groups` argument)"**.

Abaixo segue a base, e os códigos:

```
  base<-data.frame(expand.grid(FAT1=1:4,FAT2=1:2,FAT3=1:2,AVA=1:6,REP=1:3),
VAR1=runif(3*96,0,1),
VAR2=runif(3*96,-1.5,0),
VAR3=runif(3*96,0,2.5))

require(reshape2)
require(plyr)
require(tidyverse)

mbase<-base %>% pivot_longer(cols=all_of(c("VAR1","VAR2","VAR3")),names_to = "variable",values_to = "value")




dcast(ddply(mbase, .(FAT1,FAT2,FAT3,AVA,variable), summarise, soma=sum(value)),FAT1*FAT2*FAT3*AVA~variable,fun.aggregate = sum,value.var ="soma" )
# (FAT1=1,FAT2=1,FAT3=1,AVA=1)$VAR1 = 1.704

sum(subset(base,FAT1==1 & FAT2==1 & FAT3==1 & AVA==1)[,"VAR1"])
# = 1.704



base %>% pivot_longer(cols=all_of(c("VAR1","VAR2","VAR3")),names_to = "variable",values_to = "value")%>%
  group_by(FAT1,FAT2,FAT3,AVA,variable) %>%  summarise(soma = sum(value)) %>% spread(variable,soma)
```

Comment: Você pode dar um exemplo de como você quer a resposta final? Porque pelo que entendi seu código está certo, o resultado da fórmula com `tidyverse` é o mesmo que com o `dcast`, apesar da impressão não ser exatamente a mesma.

Comment: Já viu aquilo de nem eu saber responder, porque uma hora estava funcionando, ai parou, parou tanto que tive de gerar essa pergunta, e agora, funcionou :'/ , coisas do R que faz a gente passar vergonha. de qualquer forma, vou testar as soluções do Rui Barradas, para suprimir as mensagens!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estes dois exemplos dão em cada linha valores diferentes das somas. O primeiro exemplo é o da pergunta, só com `ungroup` no fim de modo a obter `TRUE` quando os resultados são comparados com o segundo método,muito mais simples.

Quanto à segunda pergunta, para não ter as mensagens do `summarise` segue-se o que está na documentação, `help('summarise')`,

> When `.groups` is not specified, you either get `"drop_last"` when all the
> results are size 1, or `"keep"` if the size varies. In addition, a
> message informs you of that choice, unless the option
> `"dplyr.summarise.inform"` is set to `FALSE`.

```
op <- options(dplyr.summarise.inform = FALSE)

mbase <- base %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = all_of(c("VAR1", "VAR2", "VAR3")),
    names_to = "variable",
    values_to = "value"
  ) %>% 
  group_by(FAT1, FAT2, FAT3, AVA, variable) %>% 
  summarise(soma = sum(value)) %>% 
  spread(variable, soma) %>%
  ungroup()


mbase2 <- base %>% 
  group_by(FAT1, FAT2, FAT3, AVA) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(starts_with("VAR")), sum) %>%
  ungroup()


identical(mbase, mbase2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Vou testar o código pra suprimir as mensgens, (não sei o porque não estava, funcionando!), de qualquer forma **obrigado!** ( acho que deve ser algum pacote que estou chamando depois do `tidyverse`, vou colocar todos antes! ( onde você chamou depois o comando `op`???

Comment: @JeanKarlos A variável `op` significa `old_options`, pode depois ser reposta com `options(op)`.